# Angular6 Router navigate to multiple child routes that share the same component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-routing

I have multiple child components that share the same component which works fine, however, I cannot route between the pages as it appears Angular suspects the component is already loaded. Is it possible to reload the component when attempting to route to these child routes?

```
const ServicesRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: '',
        component: StructureComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'services',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                component: servicesComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'one',
                        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                        component: servicesComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'two',
                        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                        component: servicesComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'three',
                        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                        component: servicesComponent,
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'four',
                        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                        component: servicesComponent,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

Comment: Looks like AuthGaurd is blocking it, remove Gaurd and check

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you are creating different page for each route if they share the same component. You could use a parameter like so `path: 'home/:id'`.

Comment: @GreatHawkeye You have a very fair point there (feel like an idiot). I will make the changes accordingly and get back with you.

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I've updated the route to include /:service, however, the contents of the component stay the same when attempting to route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to create a same page for each route and use parameters like so : `path: 'home/:id'` .

It won't solve your problem though.
You have to use RXJS there. For example :

`this.route.paramMap
      .pipe(
        map((paramMap) => Number.parseInt(paramMap.get('id') || '1', 10)),
        switchMap((id) => this.myService.getData(id))
      ).subscribe((data) => this.data = data);`

this.route.paramMap is an Observable which you can subscribe to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [runGuardsAndResolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers).
For example try this :

```
{
        path: '',
        component: StructureComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
        children: [...]
}
```