# Angular 7 - Unload Component and Load again

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a form that I submit and it is available at any route. If I submit the form, it will then load my component, but when I submit my form twice with different params, my component is not reloaded.
I guess Angular does not load the current component, if it already was loaded, but in this case I actually want that because the user gave new data.

Please do not judge I am not an angular pro.

Some code:

`some-form-component.component.ts` (onSubmit is called when submitting the form):

```
onSubmit() {
  if (some-form-component.isFormDataValid(this.formData)) {
    this.router.navigate([this.formData.a, this.formData.b, this.formData.c]);
  } else {
    this.snackBar.open(
      'Some error message.',
      'OK',
      {
        duration: 4000,
      });
  }
}
```

FullUrl would later be `aaa.com/search/a/b/c` for example.

Comment: can you provide code?. Relevant code.

Comment: Sure @Yoarthur.

Comment: I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737269/6281648 :). No more need of helping ;).

Comment: you should subscribe to `route.paramMap` in component onInit. By design if there is no route change the component will not reload.

Comment: @nircraft is right. You should not force the component to reload. Use this solution instead : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53190384/5573733